# Hibernate firing queries un-necessarily

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having a UsersCC class, having three instance variable
1)   userID which is marked as @ID
2)   userPswd which is of string type
3)   userDOB is of Date type

I created an object of UserCC class and set these values, having hbm2ddl.auto set to "CREATE".

Then i changed the class structure and added one more field in it, set show_SQL property to "true".  and hbm2dll.auto set to "UPDATE"
4)   userEmail is of String type

when i see the console after again saving an object, its firing below queries.

Hibernate: alter table UsersCC add column userID int4 not null
Hibernate: alter table UsersCC add column userDOB date
Hibernate: alter table UsersCC add column userEmail varchar(255)
Hibernate: alter table UsersCC add column userPswd varchar(255)
Hibernate: insert into UsersCC (userDOB, userEmail, userPswd, userID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)

My question is what the need of altering all the columns. why didn't altering the last column was not enough to make this work. i.e
(Hibernate: alter table UsersCC add column userEmail varchar(255) )

Comment: What is datatype of userEmail into database ? Is it already varchar(255) so hibernate is happy.

Comment: Yes, its varchar(255). data is being intact. there is no change in data which i inserted before setting hbm2ddl.auto to "UPDATE". however when i set it to "UPDATE", its altering all column, that is what making me confuse. anyway, thanks for your reply.